# Is it possible to select this in one SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In the database there are two tables:

secondNames:

```
id | name     
--------------
 1 | John     
 2 | Peter   
 3 | Michael
```

names:

```
id | name  | secondNames_id 
----------------------------
 1 | Jack  |       2        
 2 | Harry |       2        
 3 | James |       1
```

Say I have name from secondName table and want to select names of people who has that second name. Being a begginer at SQL I do like this:

```
SELECT id FROM secondNames WHERE name = 'some name';
SELECT name FROM names WHERE secondNames_id = 'id from first select';
```

Is it possible to do this in one query and how?

Comment: Join the names table by the `id = secondNames_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select n.name
from secondNames as sn
inner join names as n on n.secondNames_ID = sn.id
where sn.name = 'some name'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [scalar subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq):

```
SELECT name
FROM names
WHERE secondNames_id = (SELECT id
                        FROM secondNames
                        WHERE name = 'some name');
```